# I want to dynamically resize the text to fit the width of the widget

Tags: flutter

[image]
I want to dynamically resize the text to fit the width of the widget.

Currently, text and images are displayed in Row().
The text is in Column() and is in two columns.

```
 SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: IntrinsicWidth(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                              child: Text(
                                _localeDate,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                              child: Text(
                                _time,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: _banner == null
                                ? Container()
                                : Container(
                                    height: 52, child: AdWidget(ad: _banner!))),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Image(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage(url)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

This is the current code, which displays well on the iPad, but sticks out on the iPhone.

Comment: Wrap Text with FittedBox and set fit property to fitWidth

Comment: You may use IntrinsicWidth to wrap your row

Comment: I did fix all .

Comment: but i can not success ,

Comment: are you check this IntrinsicWidth?

Comment: Can you please attach a screen shot of the problem and the expected output ?

Comment: Okay, so can you please give me a snippet so I can attach or post it as an answer? so others get help to

Comment: Sorry , I did find issue, I did change code.

Comment: Please don't update the question. also, post questions as previous one and I posted answers so other communities may help our q&a session

Comment: i post the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code :

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: IntrinsicWidth(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: const [
            FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              child: Text(
                "21/12/22",
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              child: Text(
                "2:3",
                style: TextStyle(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    const Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Image(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/business-woman-drawing-global-structure-260nw-1006041130.jpg")))
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks , I can success . but I have error .

Comment: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFittedBox#107c7 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
  creator: FittedBox ← Column ← Stack ← IntrinsicWidth ← Padding ← Expanded ← Row ← MediaQuery ←
    Padding ← SafeArea ← Align ← ColoredBox ← ⋯

Comment: Please try with mainAxisSize in row set as max and issue you wrote is occurs due to expanded widget

Comment: child: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [

Comment: It is same . Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox#b7665 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Comment: I updated the answer again and run my machine not getting any render error , please try new answer

Comment: Sorry , I did change code now .

Comment: I would like you to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250898/discussion-between-tdayo-and-rahulvflutterandroid).